# Gremlin to Gremlinq translation: How to select those edges whose out vertices satisfy a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, gremlin

I have this gremlin query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Resource').has('name', 'Studio')
.inE("IsAssignedTo")
.as("roles")
.outV().has("User", "name", "Jon Doe").as("user")
.select("roles")
```

I am trying to convert it into Gremlinq query. My silly solution is this. But this one is not giving me accurate result

```
await _qs.V<T>(itemNode.Id!)
                .In<IsAssignedTo>()
                .OfType<User>()
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                .As((_, user) => _.OutE<IsAssignedTo>()
                    .As((_, assignment) => _.Select(assignment)))
                .Values(a => a.RoleCode)
                .ToArrayAsync();
```

I would appreciate any help from Gremlinq experts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem

```
 await _qs.V<T>(itemNode.Id!)
            .InE<IsAssignedTo>()
            .As((__, edge) => 
                __.OutV<User>()
                    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                    .Select(edge))
```

Got the inspiration from this Github (un related) issue [No Way to Make Labels Variable](https://github.com/ExRam/ExRam.Gremlinq/issues/43#issuecomment-573978393)
. Thank you @jonlave!